# Как правильно использовать AsyncTask? (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Наследую `AsyncTask` и переопределяю методы `onPostExecute`, `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground`. После вызова `doInBackground` не следует вызов `onPostExecute` в UI потоке. `isCancelled()` все это время возвращает `false`. Может дело в UI потоке (в самой `Activity`)?

**Код**

> **class MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InternetImageAdapter adapter = new InternetImageAdapter(this);
        ListView lv = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.elementsListView));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> **class InternetImageAdapter**

```
public class InternetImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private AsyncImageLoader imageLoader;
    private HashMap<String, String> urls;
    private Context context;

    public InternetImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        imageLoader = new AsyncImageLoader(context);
        urls = new HashMap<String, String>();
        urls.put("img25", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/bufrchggsob2j6t/WRC-1.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return urls.values().toArray()[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
        View view = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image_item, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if (imageView != null) {
            String key = (String) urls.keySet().toArray()[position];
            String url = urls.get(key);

            imageLoader.setImageViewReference(key, imageView);
            imageLoader.start(url);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

> **class AsyncDataLoader**

```
public abstract class AsyncDataLoader<T> extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, AsyncTaskResult<T>> {

    protected Context context;
    protected BaseLoaderStrategy<T> dataLoader;
    private static final int MAX_READ_TIMEOUT = 10000; // ms
    private static final int MAX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 15000; // ms

    public AsyncDataLoader(Context context, BaseLoaderStrategy<T> dataLoader) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.dataLoader = dataLoader;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<T> doInBackground(String ... params) {
        AsyncTaskResult<T> resultData = null;

        if(!isCancelled()) {
            resultData = new AsyncTaskResult<T>();
            try {
                if (!checkConnection()) {
                    throw new LoadDataException("Cannot get connection");
                }
                List<T> dataList = loadData(params[0]);
                resultData.setData(dataList);
            } catch (LoadDataException e) {
                resultData.setError(e);
            } 
        }
        return resultData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<T> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null) {
            if (result.getError() == null) {
                onSuccess(result.getData());
            } else {
                onError(result.getError());
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onError(Exception error);
    protected abstract void onSuccess(List<T> data);

    private List<T> loadData(String streamUrl) throws LoadDataException {
        InputStream is = null;
        List<T> resultData = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(streamUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(MAX_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setReadTimeout(MAX_READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            if (is != null) {
                resultData = dataLoader.loadData(is);
            } else {
                throw new LoadDataException();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new LoadDataException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LoadDataException(e);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new LoadDataException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultData;
    }

    public void start(String url) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
            executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
        } else {
            execute(url);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> **class AsyncImageLoader**

```
public class AsyncImageLoader extends AsyncDataLoader<Bitmap> {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private String imageKey;

    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache;
    private static int MB = 1024 * 1024;

    public AsyncImageLoader(Context context) {
        super(context, new ImageLoaderStrategy());

        ActivityManager activityMngr = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int memClass = activityMngr.getMemoryClass();

        lruCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(memClass * MB) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
                return value.getRowBytes() * value.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key,
                    Bitmap oldValue, Bitmap newValue) {    
                if (evicted) {
                    oldValue.recycle();
                }
                if (newValue != null) {
                    newValue.recycle();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void setImageViewReference(String imageKey, ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageKey = imageKey;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Bitmap bitmap = lruCache.get(imageKey);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Bitmap> data) {
        if (data.size() > 0) {
            Bitmap bitmap = data.get(0);

            lruCache.put(imageKey, bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывать doInBackground не надо

Надо делать примерно так:

```
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask();
task.execute();
```

Либо, если я неправильно понял ваш вопрос, неплохо увидеть код и тогда будет легче что-то подсказать

Comment: нет, я вызываю как вы и писали. выложил код

Comment: По-моему у меня когда-то была похожая проблема и была она в методе getView(...) у адаптера (попробуйте посмотреть хотя бы сколько раз у вас вызывается этот метод и проследите его работу)